# Reply to multiple users telegram (Message Id) PHP Bot

Tags: bots, telegram, telegram-bot

I have question, When I send a message from my api to several users, the message_id is the same for all users or each chat have a different id?

because when I try to send a reply to all my user I get this error

https://api.telegram.org/mytoken/sendMessage?chat_id=loopIDs&parse_mode=HTML&text=test&reply_to_message_id=1338

request failed! HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request in ...

{
"ok": false,
"error_code": 400,
"description": "Bad Request: reply message not found"
}

the message id I get it when I send the request to telegram api.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

each message has a different id, and you should reply to each message of any user separately.

```
https://api.telegram.org/mytoken/sendMessage?chat_id=user1ID&parse_mode=HTML&text=test&reply_to_message_id=user1MessageID
https://api.telegram.org/mytoken/sendMessage?chat_id=user2ID&parse_mode=HTML&text=test&reply_to_message_id=user2MessageID
```

Comment: OK thanks, any idea how I save the message and message_ids of all my users in my DB?

Comment: That's a very broad question! if you reply to your users' messages immediately after receiving them, you won't need to save them. otherwise, if you only need the ID of the last message of users, you can parse each users' messages' json and save them as an attribute of your user model and if you need all the messageIDs of users, you should define messages model and establish one-to-many relationship and blah blah. search for tutorials about how to connect to the db in your preferred language.